# deploy pl sql .sql scripts with sqlplus in linux

Tags: sql, deployment, plsql, sqlplus

As of now I am running(Automated) sql scripts in windows cmd through SQLPLUS.
for example:

```
sqlplus username@sid/password    

@D:\path\emp.sql      
/        
@D:\path\emp_ins.sql          
/     
@D:\path\emp_func.sql     
/       
@D:\path\emp_proc.sql      
/       
@D:\path\emp_index.sql    
/
```

as now it is working fine with windows, 
After my connectivity is established linux sqlplus.
How do i impliment the same functionality when i connect through linux?
i tried giving the path @path/emp.sql
Pls Help.
If you need any extra information pls comment.

Answer (score 0):

This might not provide exactly what you need but if you are saving all of your scripts in the same directory i have always found best practice is to navigate there before launching sql plus..

e.g.
 - Launch Terminal
 - cd /usr//MyDirectory
 - launch sqlplus (sqlplus username/password@SID)
 - @MyScript.sql

Always works for me.

If you need any help in terms of using terminal there is lots online, I found this on cd in 1 search..
http://www.linfo.org/cd.html

Hope this helps!